# Отсортировать по количеству вхождений подстрок

Tags: mysql, mysqli

```
SUM((title_prev LIKE '%yandex%' or description LIKE '%yandex%') and (title_prev LIKE '%отзывы%' or description LIKE '%отзывы%')) AS total_matches

SELECT *, SUM((title_prev LIKE '%yandex%' or description LIKE '%yandex%') and (title_prev LIKE '%отзывы%' or description LIKE '%отзывы%')) AS total_matches 
          FROM news 
          where (title_prev LIKE '%yandex%' or description LIKE '%yandex%') and (title_prev LIKE '%отзывы%' or description LIKE '%отзывы%') 
          order by total_matches desc Limit 5
```

Пытаюсь отсортировать по количеству вхождений подстрок, но вместо 5 записей. На выходе имею всего 1, в чем дело?

Comment: А где group by, который бы эти самые строки при наличии sum сделал

Comment: может вы хотели использовать `+` вместо sum ?

Comment: не совсем понимаю, что за +? как я понял он мне подсчитал общее количество вхождений во всех строчках таблицы, а не количество вхождений в каждой записи таблицы. Как через group by или я ничего не понял...

Comment: функция sum() это агрегатная функция, она для того и сделана что бы суммировать значения в группе строк. Вам либо надо как то ограничить группу, если она нужна. Либо не использовать sum, если надо считать в пределах одной строки и использовать обычное сложение `(title_prev LIKE '%yandex%' or description LIKE '%yandex%') + (title_prev LIKE '%отзывы%' or description LIKE '%отзывы%')`

Comment: `SELECT *, ((title_prev LIKE '%yandex%' or description LIKE '%yandex%') + (title_prev LIKE '%отзывы%' or description LIKE '%отзывы%')) AS total_matches 
          FROM news 
          where (title_prev LIKE '%yandex%' or description LIKE '%yandex%') and (title_prev LIKE '%отзывы%' or description LIKE '%отзывы%') 
          order by total_matches desc Limit 5`

Comment: Ни asc ни desc, все на своих местах, сортировка не работает.

Comment: Что значит 'не работает'. Так не бывает, какой то порядок то она должна задать. И вы же понимаете, что вы считаете не количество вхождений, а сумму наличия одного слова и второго. два yandex ни как на выходе 2 не дадут

Comment: Если вам нужно сортировать по релевантности лучше все таки использовать полнотекстовый поиск http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html На like далеко не уедешь

Comment: юзайте полнотекстовый поиск. повтрю коммент к предыдущему вашему вопросу

Comment: Работает с fulltext